# OpenSSL 1.1.1a OPENSSL_API_COMPAT issues in GCC 4.4

Tags: c++, openssl, backwards-compatibility, gcc4.4

I have a C++ code which uses Openssl 1.1.1a. When this c++ code is executed in gcc4.4 there is link error

```
undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'
undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup'
```

The same c++ code is building file with windows.

It uses EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init() & EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup() from evp.h of openssl.

In evp.h these macros are defined as below.

```
# if OPENSSL_API_COMPAT < 0x10100000L
#  define EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(c)      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset(c)
#  define EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(c)   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset(c)
# endif
```

Somewhere in opensslconf.h the following is declared

```
#ifndef OPENSSL_MIN_API
# define OPENSSL_MIN_API 0
#endif

#if !defined(OPENSSL_API_COMPAT) || OPENSSL_API_COMPAT < OPENSSL_MIN_API
# undef OPENSSL_API_COMPAT
# define OPENSSL_API_COMPAT OPENSSL_MIN_API
#endif
```

So ideally OPENSSL_API_COMPAT should be initialized to 0 which would have defined the two functions which are linked by the C++ code.

Somehow these two functions are not defined while building in gcc4.4.

I tried defining the OPENSSL_API_COMPAT to 0 while building using 
-DOPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0 but still no luck

Ideally these functions should be defined when the macro OPENSSL_API_COMPAT is set to 0. No where else this macro is manipulated in c++ code or other library.

What and where could the macro be altered ? Would be of great help if any openssl expert give some insight here.

Comment: Sounds like a version-conflict: old headers mixed with new libraries.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond  I re-compiled the openssl 1.1.1a in gcc4.4 and using the include file and the libraries extracted from it. So it is all same.

Comment: I mean you should compile your C++ program with the new headers and link it with the new libraries.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, you mean linking to new openssl libraries, right ? Yes, the C++ code is built including the new headers and linked with new libs of openssl 1.1.1a

Comment: I think it is new headers and old libraries (0.9.6 openssl). Maybe post the linker invocation. Openssl 1.1 might be installed as libssl-1.1 or something similar.